# How to make a floating island in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game with islands, I am using unity terrain for that. The problem is, I don't want regular I want floating ones. The problem with Unity terrain is that you can only create islands like this:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

I was thinking about creating another terrain and then flipping it upside down, but the problem there would be that the alignment of the two terrains would not be the same.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance
Emiel

Comment: Have you tried making it in blender or maya

Comment: The problem is that I want to make it with unity terrain

Comment: unity terrain is not made to support this kind of feature, you should try to make your own implementation or use a package from the asset store

Comment: Create your terrain then convert it to a Mesh.  Now you play with it however you want.  This is assuming you don't want to see an underside - like the floating islands seen in 'Avatar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is to create the shape of your floating island, use the paint holes brush to remove the leftover outer areas you don't want to use for your island, duplicate the terrain and use the brushes on the duplicated one to look like an underside, then flip it (I'd probably convert it to a normal mesh if I did it). Then simply cover up the edges with rocks or other things to hide that seam where the two terrains meet.

This way, at least the top of the floating island remains a usable Unity terrain, just in case you intend to use terrain shaders on it.